# Omnioutliner random sort

Tags: mac, omnioutliner

Is there a way to sort my OmniOutliner columns by a random value for something like picking students in your class at random for groups?

Comment: What does sort by a random value mean?

Comment: I need to be able to sort the rows in a random order. Generally in Excel this is done by using the Rand function in the cells of a row and sorting by that row.

Answer (score 1):

To get a random number, use `rand()` (as seen [here](http://www.omnigroup.com/mailman/archive/macosx-dev/2002-January/034618.html)). Then sort by the random numbers.

Comment: I don't see how to use the rand(), the link did not give any information. Where do I use it. In the cell?

Comment: Yes. Its like a regular function.

Comment: I don't see how to use it. I've put it into the cell but it does not give back a value like in Excel. Can you elaborate?